# what happens when I modify a pandas dataframe in the following way

Tags: python, pandas

trying to understand this behavior (why it happens; and if it was intentional, then what was the motivation for it to be done this way)

So I create a dataframe

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,2)))


          0         1
0  0.548814  0.715189
1  0.602763  0.544883
2  0.423655  0.645894
3  0.437587  0.891773
```

and I can reference columns like so

```
df.columns = ['a','b']
df.a
          0
0  0.548814
1  0.602763
2  0.423655
3  0.437587
```

I can even make, what I think is a new column

```
 df.third = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,1)))
```

but `df` is still

```
df
          0         1
0  0.548814  0.715189
1  0.602763  0.544883
2  0.423655  0.645894
3  0.437587  0.891773
```

however, `df.third` also exists (but i can't see it in my variable viewer in Spyder)

```
df.third
          0
0  0.118274
1  0.639921
2  0.143353
3  0.944669
```

if I wanted to add a third column, I'd have to do the following

```
df['third'] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,1)))

          a         b     third
0  0.548814  0.715189  0.568045
1  0.602763  0.544883  0.925597
2  0.423655  0.645894  0.071036
3  0.437587  0.891773  0.087129
```

So, my question is what's going on when I do df.third versus df['third']?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it added `third` as an attribute, you should stop accessing columns as an attribute and always use `df['third']` to avoid ambiguous behaviour.

You should get into the habit of always accessing and assigning columns using `df[col_name]`, this is to avoid problems like

```
df.mean = some_calc()
```

well the problem here is that `mean` is a method for a DataFrame

So you've then overwritten a method with some computed value.

The problem here is that this was part of the design as a convenience and the pandas for data analysis book and some early online video presentations showed this as a way of assigning to a new column but the subtle errors can be so pervasive that it really should be banned and removed IMO

Seriously I can't stress this enough, **stop referring to columns as an attribute**, it's a serious bugbear of mine and unfortunately I still see lots of answers posted showing this usage

You can see that no new column is added:

```
In [97]:
df.third = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,1)))
df.columns

Out[97]:
Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')
```

You can see that `third` was added as an attribute:

```
In [98]:
df.__dict__

Out[98]:
{'_data': BlockManager
 Items: Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')
 Axis 1: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')
 FloatBlock: slice(0, 2, 1), 2 x 4, dtype: float64,
 '_iloc': <pandas.core.indexing._iLocIndexer at 0x7e73b00>,
 '_item_cache': {},
 'is_copy': None,
 'third':           0
 0  0.844821
 1  0.286501
 2  0.459170
 3  0.243452}
```

You can see that you have an `Items`, `__data`, `Axis 1` etc but then you also have `'third'` which is an attribute

Answer (score 0):

I think you add attribute **third** to pandas data frame object
If you wanna add the column with name 'third' you must make this:

```
df['third'] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,1)))
```

Comment: The OP already stated on the last line that this works, the OP is asking why `df.third = X` doesn't work