# After rename column get keyerror

Tags: pandas, numpy, multiple-columns, rename

I have `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[7,8,9],
                   'b':[1,3,5],
                   'c':[5,3,6]})

print (df)
   a  b  c
0  7  1  5
1  8  3  3
2  9  5  6
```

Then rename first value by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36149967/2901002):

```
df.columns.values[0] = 'f'
```

All seems very nice:

```
print (df)
   f  b  c
0  7  1  5
1  8  3  3
2  9  5  6

print (df.columns)
Index(['f', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')

print (df.columns.values)
['f' 'b' 'c']
```

If select `b` it works nice:

```
print (df['b'])
0    1
1    3
2    5
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

But if select `a` it return column `f`:

```
print (df['a'])
0    7
1    8
2    9
Name: f, dtype: int64
```

And if select `f` get keyerror.

```
print (df['f'])
#KeyError: 'f'

print (df.info())
#KeyError: 'f'
```

What is problem? Can somebody explain it? Or bug?

Comment: There is a mention about this behaviour in the comments of this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11346337/3423035). Since one is modifying the internal state of this index object it might not get propagated to all instances using it. I think the using `df.rename(columns={'a': 'f'})` is the intended way to go.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You aren't expected to alter the `values` attribute.

Try `df.columns.values = ['a', 'b', 'c']` and you get:

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-61-e7e440adc404> in <module>()
> ----> 1 df.columns.values = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>
> AttributeError: can't set attribute
> ```

That's because `pandas` detects that you are trying to set the attribute and stops you.

However, it can't stop you from changing the underlying `values` object itself.

When you use `rename`, `pandas` follows up with a bunch of clean up stuff.  I've pasted the source below.

Ultimately what you've done is altered the values without initiating the clean up.  You can initiate it yourself with a followup call to `_data.rename_axis` (example can be seen in source below).  This will force the clean up to be run and then you can access `['f']`

```
df._data = df._data.rename_axis(lambda x: x, 0, True)
df['f']

0    7
1    8
2    9
Name: f, dtype: int64
```

Moral of the story: probably not a great idea to rename a column this way.

---

***but this story gets weirder***

This is fine

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[7,8,9],
                   'b':[1,3,5],
                   'c':[5,3,6]})

df.columns.values[0] = 'f'

df['f']

0    7
1    8
2    9
Name: f, dtype: int64
```

This is **not** fine

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[7,8,9],
                   'b':[1,3,5],
                   'c':[5,3,6]})

print(df)

df.columns.values[0] = 'f'

df['f']
```

> ```
> KeyError:
> ```

Turns out, we can modify the `values` attribute prior to displaying `df` and it will apparently run all the initialization upon the first `display`.  If you display it prior to changing the `values` attribute, it will error out.

***weirder still***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[7,8,9],
                   'b':[1,3,5],
                   'c':[5,3,6]})

print(df)

df.columns.values[0] = 'f'

df['f'] = 1

df['f']

   f  f
0  7  1
1  8  1
2  9  1
```

As if we didn't already know that this was a bad idea...

---

***source for `rename`***

```
def rename(self, *args, **kwargs):

    axes, kwargs = self._construct_axes_from_arguments(args, kwargs)
    copy = kwargs.pop('copy', True)
    inplace = kwargs.pop('inplace', False)

    if kwargs:
        raise TypeError('rename() got an unexpected keyword '
                        'argument "{0}"'.format(list(kwargs.keys())[0]))

    if com._count_not_none(*axes.values()) == 0:
        raise TypeError('must pass an index to rename')

    # renamer function if passed a dict
    def _get_rename_function(mapper):
        if isinstance(mapper, (dict, ABCSeries)):

            def f(x):
                if x in mapper:
                    return mapper[x]
                else:
                    return x
        else:
            f = mapper

        return f

    self._consolidate_inplace()
    result = self if inplace else self.copy(deep=copy)

    # start in the axis order to eliminate too many copies
    for axis in lrange(self._AXIS_LEN):
        v = axes.get(self._AXIS_NAMES[axis])
        if v is None:
            continue
        f = _get_rename_function(v)

        baxis = self._get_block_manager_axis(axis)
        result._data = result._data.rename_axis(f, axis=baxis, copy=copy)
        result._clear_item_cache()

    if inplace:
        self._update_inplace(result._data)
    else:
        return result.__finalize__(self)
```

Comment: Very interesting research!

Comment: I am thinking about how can `print` cause this difference. Do you have some idea why? Never seen it before.

Comment: @jezrael my theory is that there is initialization that happens upon the first print.

Comment: But it is bug, becuase influence of `print`? I think it is impossible, but maybe I am wrong .

Comment: @jezrael when print is called, it calls the __repr__ method. At that point I'm guessing pandas runs some caching scripts if they haven't run before.

Comment: Hmmm, I check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42978728/2901002) and try print `print (df.__dict__)` before and after `rename`. And after `print(df)` it is changed, some `_iloc` is added. But why? It is really weird.

Comment: @jezrael agreed.  Definitely weird

Comment: Thank you for digging into this. I'm still confused on the best approach to rename columns. I'm using the 'df._data = df._data.rename_axis(lambda x: x, 0, True)' workaround for now.

Comment: @adivis12 this issue is unrelated to how you should rename columns or an index.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46192213/2336654