# How to prevent json_normalize from repeating column headings in Pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

My json is structured as follows:

```
{
   "data": {
              "item1": {
                       "field1": "foo",
                       "field2": "bar",
                       "field3": "baz"
                       },
              "item2": {
                       "field1": "foo1",
                       "field2": "bar1",
                       "field3": "baz1"
                       },
           }
}
```

When I normalize this data structure using `pd.io.json.json_normalize`, I get a data frame with 1 row and the column headings repeated for each data item. How do I get the repeated columns to appear as rows instead of columns?

I currently get this

```
field1 | field2 | field3 | field1 |field2 | field3

foo     | bar    | baz    | foo1   | bar1  | baz1
```

What I want is:

```
field1 | field2 | field3 |


foo     | bar    | baz

foo1    | bar1   | baz1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
In [31]: d
Out[31]:
{'data': {'item1': {'field1': 'foo', 'field2': 'bar', 'field3': 'baz'},
  'item2': {'field1': 'foo1', 'field2': 'bar1', 'field3': 'baz1'}}}

In [32]: pd.DataFrame(d['data']).T
Out[32]:
      field1 field2 field3
item1    foo    bar    baz
item2   foo1   bar1   baz1
```

Comment: I suspect you already upvoted... but I [**edited the post**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43292413/2336654)... this is weird stuff :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to convert the `data` to list, and then use `json_normalize` to normalize the data:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

content={"data": {"item1": {"field1": "foo","field2": "bar","field3": "baz"},"item2": {"field1": "foo1","field2": "bar1","field3": "baz1"},}}

content["data"]=content["data"].values()

result = json_normalize(content,"data")

print(result)
```

Output:

```
  field1 field2 field3
0   foo1   bar1   baz1
1    foo    bar    baz
```