# Pandas rename column by position?

Tags: python, pandas

I was just wondering if I can rename column names by their positions.
I know how to rename them by their actual names using:

`df.rename(columns = {})`

How do I do it if I do not know the column names and know only their positions?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

try this

```
df.rename(columns={ df.columns[1]: "your value" }, inplace = True)
```

Comment: For some reason, I needed `df=df.rename({})` after this for it to take effect

Comment: I would go with John Zwinck's solution.  This solution will actually lead to some strange bugs, as noted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291781/after-rename-column-get-keyerror

Comment: I tried this solution and got really weird errors down the track in my code. I was hard to find the problem and it all came down to use this solution. So I confirm what @rnorris explained - TRY AND AVOID THIS AS IT MAY LEAD TO PROBLEMS. Try John Zwinck's solution instead, which doesn't cause problems.

Comment: Use `df.rename(columns={ df.columns[1]: "your value"}, inplace=True)`.  Otherwise a copy is returned.  See the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

Comment: is it possible to do this without having "df" in the rename statement ?

Comment: This approach only works if all columns names are unique. However, if say, 
`df.columns[1] = df.columns[5]` then calling just `df.columns[1]` will change both `df.columns[1`] and `df.columns[5]`.

Comment: If you know exactly which specific column you wish to rename, probably just try something like `df.columns.values[1] = "some new column name"`

Answer (score 60):

You can do this:

```
df.rename(columns={ df.columns[1]: "whatever" })
```

Comment: This didn't work with the following column name `International airline passengers: monthly totals in thousands. Jan 49 ? Dec 60`

Comment: Note that as for the standard behavior there will be a copy created and returned. You can add `inplace=True` after the `}` to modifiy the object in place.

Comment: Not OP but thanks a lot for the answer. Could you tell me what does the keyword `inplace` do in this case please? I've been trying to figure it out as I could run the code when I set it to `True`. Thanks again.

Comment: @BowenLiu: Have you read the documentation?  It describes `inplace`.