# Pandas rename column by position with multilevel column name

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to easily rename the name of the 2nd column of Pandas DataFrame in the case below?

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2], 'b':[3, 2]}).groupby('a', as_index=False).agg({'b':['sum', 'count']})
```

I tried the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43759921/pandas-rename-column-by-position) but this dataframe has a multi-level column name (i.e. `a.columns[1]` is `["b","sum"]` instead of a single string like `"bsum"`). The following code won't work.

```
a.rename(columns={a.columns[1]:'new_name'})
```

For my case, it is not very easy to figure out the exact column name so I want to have a way to change the name of the column based on it's position.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you mention the output you are expecting for the sample data in the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the target level in [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
a.rename(columns={'sum':'new_name'}, level=1)
```

For a dynamic renaming like in your answer:

```
a.rename(columns={a.columns[1][1]:'new_name'}, level=1)
#    a        b      
#      new_name count
# 0  1        3     1
# 1  2        2     1

a.rename(columns={a.columns[1][0]:'new_name'}, level=0)
#    a new_name      
#           sum count
# 0  1        3     1
# 1  2        2     1
```

Answer (score 3):

You need specify position of columns and position of levels first:

```
a = a.rename(columns={a.columns[1][1]:'new_name'}, level=1)
print (a)
   a        b      
     new_name count
0  1        3     1
1  2        2     1
```

---

```
a = a.rename(columns={a.columns[1][0]:'new_name'}, level=0)
print (a)
   a new_name      
          sum count
0  1        3     1
1  2        2     1
```