# Rename column by column index pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to rename column 1 of the following dataframe as 'Ref'.
I have many columns and thus can't rename each or set names for each.

```
data = [['TC1', 103, 563], ['TC2', 1567, 1290], ['TC3', 1467, 567]] 

dftrash=pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Card', '', ''])
```

This is the dataframe

```
    Card        
0   TC1 1037    8563
1   TC2 1567    1290
2   TC3 1467    567
```

Now I want to rename the 1st column as 'Ref'.
I tried this

```
dftrash.rename(columns={dftrash.columns[1]:'REF'},inplace=True)
```

which renames all columns with similar heading as column[1].

```
    Card REF    REF
0   TC1 1037    8563
1   TC2 1567    1290
2   TC3 1467    567
```

Answer (score 1):

Columns in pandas are immutable - your best bet would be to make numpy array, set values by indexing and assign back:

```
#pandas 0.24+
a = dftrash.columns.to_numpy()
#pandas below
#a = dftrash.columns.to_numpy()
a[1] = 'REF'
print (a)
['Card' 'REF' '']
```

Or convert values to list:

```
a = dftrash.columns.tolist()
a[1] = 'REF'
print (a)
['Card', 'REF', '']
```

---

```
dftrash.columns = a
print (dftrash)
  Card   REF      
0  TC1   103   563
1  TC2  1567  1290
2  TC3  1467   567
```

[In past versions of pandas was problem assign to numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43291781/2901002), it seems now it working nice, but still recommended first solution:

```
dftrash.columns.values[1] = "REF"
print (dftrash)
  Card   REF      
0  TC1   103   563
1  TC2  1567  1290
2  TC3  1467   567
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael! This is of course a way. I was wondering whether a renaming by indexing such as rename(columns={1:'Ref'}) is possible someway. I found this renaming by index in some threads but does not work.

Comment: @haphaZard - no, it not working, because duplicated columns names, so need another solutions like in answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the job:

```
dftrash.columns = ['REF'] + list(dftrash.columns[1:])
```

It, basically, creates new name list that pandas can use to rename columns. Or more generally:

```
new_names = list(dftrash.columns)
new_names[0] = 'REF'
dftrash.columns = new_names
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the columnnames, edit the column name, and insert again

```
data = [['TC1', 103, 563], ['TC2', 1567, 1290], ['TC3', 1467, 567]]
dftrash=pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Card', '', '']) 
colnames = list(dftrash.columns)
colnames[1] = "REF"
dftrash.set_axis(colnames, axis=1, inplace=True)
```