# Create a column based on computation of a another column

Tags: python, pandas, self-join

I would like to create another column based on the sales for the previous week. Here is the sample input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Week':[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5],
                   'Category':['Red','White','Red','White','Red','White','Red','White','Red','White','Red','White','Red','White','Red','White','Red','White','Red','White'],
                   'id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                   'Sales':[100,200,300,400,100,200,300,400,100,200,100,200,300,400,100,200,300,400,100,200],
                  'Sales_others':[10,20,30,40,10,20,30,40,10,20,10,20,30,40,10,20,30,40,10,20]})
print(df)
```

Based on this, i would like to create another column which is nothing but the sales of the previous week. Here is the sample of the desired output

```
    df_output = pd.DataFrame({'Week':[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5],
                       'Category':['Red','White','Red','White','Red','White','Red','White','Red','White','Red','White','Red','White','Red','White','Red','White','Red','White'],
                       'id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                       'Sales':[100,200,300,400,100,200,300,400,100,200,100,200,300,400,100,200,300,400,100,200],
                      'Sales_others':[10,20,30,40,10,20,30,40,10,20,10,20,30,40,10,20,30,40,10,20],
                      'Sales_previous_week':[0,0,100,200,300,400,100,200,300,400,0,0,100,200,300,400,100,200,300,400]})
print(df_output)
```

Am finding it hard to create what would be a self join. The previous week should only be influenced by sales file and i should be able to retain the "sales_others" column

--Edit
Adding original code

```
CR_UK_NL_Weeklevel['PREVIOUS_WEEK'] = CR_UK_NL_Weeklevel.groupby(['RETAIL_SITE_ID','CATEGORY_NAME'])['CURRENT_WEEK'].shift(fill_value=0)
print(CR_UK_NL_Weeklevel)
```

Renaming columns

```
CR_UK_NL_Weeklevel.columns.values[4] = 'CURRENT_WEEK'
CR_UK_NL_Weeklevel.columns.values[3] = 'LAST_YEAR_WEEK'
CR_UK_NL_Weeklevel.columns.values
```

Trying to implement solution:

```
CR_UK_NL_Weeklevel['PREVIOUS_WEEK'] = CR_UK_NL_Weeklevel.groupby(['RETAIL_SITE_ID','CATEGORY_NAME'])['CURRENT_WEEK'].shift(fill_value=0)
print(CR_UK_NL_Weeklevel)
```

[78]:

```
CR_UK_NL_Weeklevel['PREVIOUS_WEEK'] = CR_UK_NL_Weeklevel.groupby(['RETAIL_SITE_ID','CATEGORY_NAME'])['CURRENT_WEEK'].shift(fill_value=0)
print(CR_UK_NL_Weeklevel)
```

--Error

*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 CR_UK_NL_Weeklevel['PREVIOUS_WEEK'] = CR_UK_NL_Weeklevel.groupby(['RETAIL_SITE_ID','CATEGORY_NAME'])['CURRENT_WEEK'].shift(fill_value=0)
      2 print(CR_UK_NL_Weeklevel)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in **getitem**(self, key)
    273         else:
    274             if key not in self.obj:
--> 275                 raise KeyError("Column not found: {key}".format(key=key))
    276             return self._gotitem(key, ndim=1)
    277 
KeyError: 'Column not found: CURRENT_WEEK'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are always same categories per week and consecutive weeks use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) grouping by `Category` column:

```
df['Sales_PREVIOUS'] = df.groupby('Category')['Sales'].shift(fill_value=0)
print (df)
   Week Category  Sales  Sales_PREVIOUS
0     1      Red    100               0
1     1    White    200               0
2     2      Red    300             100
3     2    White    400             200
4     3      Red    100             300
5     3    White    200             400
6     4      Red    300             100
7     4    White    400             200
8     5      Red    100             300
9     5    White    200             400
```

Another idea with pivoting is use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), then [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series` and last add new column by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
s = df.pivot('Week','Category','Sales').shift(fill_value=0).stack()
df = df.join(s.rename('Sales_PREVIOUS WEEK'), on=['Week','Category'])
```

EDIT:

With new data add column `id`:

```
df['Sales_PREVIOUS'] = df.groupby(['id','Category'])['Sales'].shift(fill_value=0)
```

And for second solution:

```
s = df.set_index(['Week','id','Category'])['Sales'].unstack([1,2]).shift(fill_value=0).unstack()
df = df.join(s.rename('Sales_PREVIOUS WEEK'), on=['id','Category','Week'])
print (df)
    Week Category  id  Sales  Sales_others  Sales_PREVIOUS WEEK
0      1      Red   1    100            10                    0
1      1    White   1    200            20                    0
2      2      Red   1    300            30                  100
3      2    White   1    400            40                  200
4      3      Red   1    100            10                  300
5      3    White   1    200            20                  400
6      4      Red   1    300            30                  100
7      4    White   1    400            40                  200
8      5      Red   1    100            10                  300
9      5    White   1    200            20                  400
10     1      Red   2    100            10                    0
11     1    White   2    200            20                    0
12     2      Red   2    300            30                  100
13     2    White   2    400            40                  200
14     3      Red   2    100            10                  300
15     3    White   2    200            20                  400
16     4      Red   2    300            30                  100
17     4    White   2    400            40                  200
18     5      Red   2    100            10                  300
19     5    White   2    200            20                  400
```

EDIT:

Problem is with columns names, use:

```
cols = CR_UK_NL_Weeklevel.columns.tolist()
cols[4] = 'CURRENT_WEEK'
cols[3] = 'LAST_YEAR_WEEK'
CR_UK_NL_Weeklevel.columns = cols
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks again Jezrael, however can i also retain a column from the dataset. Lets say i had a column called ID in the dataset, it doesnot have any relevance to the current exercise, it will be great if i can just retain it.

Comment: Order does not matter.

Comment: When i add 1 more column, the script is not working. I have made edit to the question

Comment: i used the first! but it will be great if you can help with both.

Comment: Both the solution works when i implement it on the sample set. but when i implement it in our original dataset it says "Key Error: Column does not exist[Sales]". Am not sure how to approach this, can data type be a reason? becoz am sure the column is present in the dataset

Comment: df.columns.str.replace(' ', ''). i did to make sure there were no spaces in between or after. both the output from print (df.columns.tolist()) and script is exactly the same

Comment: I know it sounds very weird. the dataset is also the same.

Comment: ['CALWEEK' 'RETAIL_SITE_ID' 'CATEGORY_NAME' 'LAST_YEAR_WEEK'
 'CURRENT_WEEK']

Comment: @vevekseetharaman - I think problem is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291781/after-rename-column-get-keyerror), edited answer for solution - last pragraph

Comment: This worked! You are amazing! I didnt know i cannot rename columns like that