# Strange behaviour. A single negative value generated in Pandas dataframe, when new column is created

Tags: python, pandas

Following is the head of the `Pandas dataframe`that I am working on.

```
test.head()

    Country_or_Other    TotalCases  TotalTests
9   USA                    2026493    21725064
10  Brazil                  710887      999836
11  Russia                  476658    13016023
12  Spain                   288797     4465338
13  UK                      287399     5731576

display(test['TotalCases'].sum())
display(test['TotalTests'].sum())

7189858

10038473
```

I am creating two new columns using simple arithmetic. The columns will calculate the value of individual observations as a % of the totals for the original variables.

```
test['TotalCases_Percent'] = 100*test['TotalCases']/test['TotalCases'].sum()
test['TotalTests_Percent'] = 100*test['TotalTests']/test['TotalTests'].sum()
test.head()


Country_or_Other    TotalCases  TotalTests  TotalCases_Percent  TotalTests_Percent
9   USA                2026493    21725064               28.19              -21.14
10  Brazil              710887      999836                9.89                1.00
11  Russia              476658    13016023                6.63               12.97
12  Spain               288797     4465338                4.02                4.45
13  UK                  287399     5731576                4.00                5.71

test[test['Country_or_Other'] == 'USA']

    Country_or_Other    TotalCases  TotalTests  TotalCases_Percent  TotalTests_Percent
9   USA                    2026493    21725064               28.19              -21.14
```

As we can see only the `**TotalTests_Percent for USA**` has generated a negative value. It should have been a +ve percentage, like all other values. Why is this? Appreciate inputs.

#

Complete relevant code from beginning being run on a new notebook

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re

req = Request('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/', headers={'User-Agent': 'Firefox/75.0'})
webpage = re.sub(r'<.*?>', lambda g: g.group(0).upper(), urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8') )

tables = pd.read_html(webpage)

df = tables[1]
df = df.rename(columns={'Country,Other': 'Country_or_Other','Serious,Critical': 'Serious_or_Critical','Tot\xa0Cases/1M pop':'Cases_per_1M_pop', 'Tests/  1M pop': 'Tests_per_1M_pop','Deaths/1M pop':'Deaths_per_1M_pop','Tests/ 1M pop':'Tests_per_1M_pop'})
df['TotalDeaths'] = df['TotalDeaths'].fillna(0).astype(int)
df['TotalRecovered'] = df['TotalRecovered'].fillna(0).astype(int)
df['TotalTests'] = df['TotalTests'].fillna(0).astype(int)

df1 = df.drop(df.index[0:8]).drop(df.index[-8:])

cum_data = df1.drop(columns=['NewCases','NewDeaths'])
cum_data['Dead_to_Recovered'] = 100*cum_data['TotalDeaths']/cum_data['TotalRecovered']
cum_data = cum_data.sort_values('TotalCases', ascending=False)

test = cum_data.loc[:,['Country_or_Other', 'TotalCases','TotalTests']]

test['TotalCases_Percent'] = 100*test['TotalCases']/test['TotalCases'].sum()
test['TotalTests_Percent'] = 100*test['TotalTests']/test['TotalTests'].sum()
test[test['Country_or_Other'] == 'USA']

    Country_or_Other    TotalCases  TotalTests  TotalCases_Percent  TotalTests_Percent
9   USA                    2026493    21725064               28.19              -21.14
```

Appreciate if check and let me know.

Comment: Not reproducible.

Comment: @mayank, what does that mean? What cannot be reproduced?

Comment: Same - we don't get a negative when rerunning your code

Comment: @Srinivas What I mean is, with the sample of the dataframe provided by you, we are not getting any `-ve` value in the `percent` columns.

Comment: @tom. I have manually checked and run the below command. There is no other USA entry in my dataframe. I simply run my notebook everyday and I don't think this problem was showing up until today.

Comment: @mayank, ok. can a way be suggested to diagnose the issue?

Comment: Something is happening in your code base that's not shown here. Restart your jupyter kernel and check every single cell. Maybe there is one cell in which you define the percentage differently.

Comment: In addition to being unreproducible as @MayankPorwal mentioned, I see that the total tests summation is not correct. It's value is `10 038 473` which is less than USA total tests for an instance `21 725 064`

Comment: I have created a new notebook with relevant code from beginning, which I am reproducing here for everyone's sake in the code (question) box. I am still getting negative % for USA. Can you all check? Also, I have restarted my original notebook kernel and restarted Jupyter itself. But experiencing same issue.

Comment: @Yasser, the sum of TotalTests is 100384730. The zero was deleted in the question box accidentally. In any case, I have reproduced the entire code block if someone wishes to check. Appreciate inputs if someone can decipher the reason for the negative %.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas here convert column to `int32` instead `int64`, so after multiple by `100` output is wrong:

```
df['TotalTests'] = df['TotalTests'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Then get `int32` and after multiple by `100` get negative values:

```
test = cum_data.loc[:,['Country_or_Other', 'TotalCases','TotalTests']]

print (test.dtypes)
Country_or_Other    object
TotalCases           int64
TotalTests           int32
dtype: object


test['TotalCases_Percent'] = 100*test['TotalCases']/test['TotalCases'].sum()
test['TotalTests_Percent'] = 100*test['TotalTests']
df = test[test['Country_or_Other'] == 'USA']

print (df)
  Country_or_Other  TotalCases  TotalTests  TotalCases_Percent  \
9              USA     2026493    21725064            28.18313   

   TotalTests_Percent  
9         -2122460896
```

Solution is convert to `np.int64`:

```
df['TotalDeaths'] = df['TotalDeaths'].fillna(0).astype(np.int64)
df['TotalRecovered'] = df['TotalRecovered'].fillna(0).astype(np.int64)
df['TotalTests'] = df['TotalTests'].fillna(0).astype(np.int64)


test = cum_data.loc[:,['Country_or_Other', 'TotalCases','TotalTests']]

print (test.dtypes)
Country_or_Other    object
TotalCases           int64
TotalTests           int64
dtype: object

test['TotalCases_Percent'] = 100*test['TotalCases']/test['TotalCases'].sum()
test['TotalTests_Percent'] = 100*test['TotalTests']/test['TotalTests'].sum()
df = test[test['Country_or_Other'] == 'USA']

print (df)
  Country_or_Other  TotalCases  TotalTests  TotalCases_Percent  \
9              USA     2026493    21725064            28.18313   

   TotalTests_Percent  
9           21.641801
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

Change `TotalTests` column dtype to `int64`.

Use:

```
df['TotalTests'] = df['TotalTests'].fillna(0).astype('int64')   ## int64
```

instead of:

```
df['TotalTests'] = df['TotalTests'].fillna(0).astype(int)       ## int32
```

**Why?**

Mathematically, after multiplying the `TotalTests` value for `USA` by 100, its value should be `2 172 506 400` which is larger than `int32` maximum value `2 147 483 648`. So, it behaved weirdly. Changing its type to `int64` provides much higher maximum value.

Generally, it is preferred to use `int64` in all columns that have large values and about to reach `int32` max value.

**Solution 2 (naive):**

Multiply by 100 after division to avoid exceeding the maximum value at any point:

```
test['TotalTests_Percent'] = (test['TotalTests']/test['TotalTests'].sum())*100
```