# how to remove a specific column from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and it has following  attributes;
id,text,created_at,retweet_count,favorite_count, source, user_id

I want to get a new dataframe by ejecting df.text lines which start with "RT".

```
non_retweeted_list = []

for i in range(len(df)):
    if (df.text[i][0] and df.text[i][1]) == ('R' and 'T'):
        pass
    else:
        non_retweeted_list.append(df[i])
```

But I get below KeyError:

```
KeyError                                  
Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/bd/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes
/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
1944  try:
-> 1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
1946             except KeyError:

.
.
.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
KeyError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-5dfc6d77a22c> in <module>()
  5         pass
  6     else: 
 ----> 7         non_retweeted_list.append(df[i])
 .
 .
 .
 KeyError: 0
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: probably an indexing error.  share a bit of the dataframe.  also, what do you get when you do `type(df.index[0])`?

Comment: also, change `df.text` to `df['text']` see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42978728/2539738

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) for mask:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['RT apple','dog','RT baladiska']})
print (df)
           text
0      RT apple
1           dog
2  RT baladiska

mask = df['text'].str.startswith('RT')
print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: text, dtype: bool

#filter out columns start with RT
df1 = df[~mask]
print (df1)
  text
1  dog

#filter values starting RT
df2 = df[mask]
print (df2)
           text
0      RT apple
2  RT baladiska
```

Alternatively:

```
mask = df['text'].str.contains('^RT')
```

Answer (score 1):

could be the way you're referencing your index.
Also, that's an odd way to check the first two characters.  Why are you doing it that way?  What do you think about the way I'm showing below?

```
non_retweeted_list = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if 'RT' == df['text'][df.index==i][0:2]:
        pass
    else:
        non_retweeted_list.append(df[df.index[i]])
```

Lastly, it's probably not a good idea to do an `if-pass` statement.  Use the negative instead

```
non_retweeted_list = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if 'RT' != df['text'][df.index==i][0:2]:
        non_retweeted_list.append(df[df.index==i])
```